# Knockout.js purify html

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a table where rows are rendered using templates. The applied template depends on the underlying row view model state, which can be "edit" or "view". So i need to use "edit-template" or "view-template" template in every particular case.
I would like the view model not to know about its representation so i dont use some *myViewModel.getTemplateName()* function. Also, there can probably be more than one 2 templates in future.
So i decided to control templates in html code like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>..</thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- ko foreach: dicts -->
        <!-- ko template: { name: function(){ return (state() == "view")? 'row-etpd-view-template' : 'row-etpd-edit-template' } } -->
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Obviuosly, it renders as:

```
<!-- ko template: { name: function(){ return (state() == "view")? 'row-etpd-view-template' : 'row-etpd-edit-template' } } -->
<tr>...</tr>
```

for **every** row. I would like to avoid so much extra-lines as well as in other cases of inline KO use. Is there a way to do it? I suppose the KO has in-memory bindings between view models and DOM elements so it probably dont need these remarks after rendering... Have ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to handle this is to use the `foreach` option of [`template`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html).

```
<tbody>
    <!-- ko template: { foreach: dicts, name: function(item) { return (item.state() == "view")? 'row-etpd-view-template' : 'row-etpd-edit-template' } } -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</tbody>
```

Comment: I have really forgotten that name function accepts current item and binding context as parameters. Thank you!